# Can I order children from different parents?

Tags: css, flexbox

Using the CSS `order` property, is it possible to order elements that don't have the same direct parent?  Using the example below, is it possible to arrange item2 visually between item1 and item3?

I can't get it to work, so I expect not; just thought I'd check.

```css
.outer, container1, container2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item1 { order: 1; }

.item2 { order: 2; }

.item3 { order: 3; }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container1">
    <p class="item1">Item 1</p>
    <p class="item3">Item 3</p>
  </div>

  <div class="container2">
    <p class="item2">Item 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @JamesWhiteley The code shouldn't be a runnable snippet because it doesn't [need to] show anything. OP clearly states the code in the Q doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No

`order` requires elements to share a parent. You need an alternative HTML structure.

> The order CSS property specifies the order used to lay out a flex or grid item in its flex or grid container. Items within the **same container** are laid out in ascending order according to their order values. Elements with the same order value are laid out in the order in which they appear in the source code.
>
> [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)